# How to prove the formula of altitude from this following triangle?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

Given: Right triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $A$ as right angle.

If $t_A$ is altitude that drawn from point $A$ to $\overline{BC}$, called $\overline{AD}$.

[image]

> Prove that $t_A = \sqrt{2}\cdot\dfrac{bc}{b+c}$

Thanks

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, that is not the altitude.

Comment: HINT: The two triangles that are made by drawing the line are similar triangles

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the picture should be like this, @Andre.: http://i57.tinypic.com/mug7qv.png. Thanks

Comment: Let $ABC$ be a right triangle, with right angle at $A$. Let the side opposite to $B$ be $b$, and the side opposite to $C$ be $c$. Then the altitude from $A$ has length $\frac{bc}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$.

Comment: If we use similarity, I always ended on your answer, @Andre. But, how can I get √2 and b+c. It seems it's impossible to get those values? Thanks

Comment: Similarity will get you the formula of the comment above. Or else one can use the fact that the area is $\frac{bc}{2}$ and also $\frac{h\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}{2}$, where $h$ is the altitude. The other formula is just wrong in general.

Comment: I actually don't know if similarity will solve the problem for those of you who are arguing over the similarity thing. It *might* work but I'm not sure

Comment: the formula you want to prove is for bisector, but not for the altiude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking @kmitov's suggestion that $\overline{AD}$ should be the *bisector* of $\angle A$, we have that $\overline{AD}$ is the diagonal of a square:

[image]

Thus,

$$\triangle BDF \sim \triangle DCE \; \implies \; \frac{s}{c-s} = \frac{b-s}{s} \; \implies \; \frac{b c}{b+c} = s = \frac{t}{\sqrt{2}} \; \implies \; t = \sqrt{2}\frac{bc}{b+c}$$

Answer (score 2):

By the picture that you drew, we have $\frac{AD}{c}=\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$, which gives $AD=\frac{bc}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$.

This is *hardly ever* equal to $\sqrt{2}\frac{bc}{b+c}$. For if we had equality, we would have $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{b+c}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$, or equivalently $2(b^2+c^2)=(b+c)^2$. This simplifies to $b^2-2bc+c^2=0$, that is, $b=c$.

So the proposed formula only gives the right answer if our triangle is right-angled and *isosceles*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, I realized that the missing thing from this problem is we need to add the reason such that this triangle is right isosceles triangle. And also this is the formula for perpendicular bisector of right triangle. Thanks for your correction, @kmitov.

Comment: how can we get √2/(b+c) if the triangle is right isosceles triangle? Thanks

Comment: Two ways. We can go through the argument of the answer. Or else, directly, let $b=c$. Then the altitude bisects the hypotenuse, so the altitude is $\frac{b\sqrt{2}}{2}$. And when $b=c$, we have $\frac{\sqrt{2}bc}{b+c}=\frac{\sqrt{2}b^2}{2b}=\frac{\sqrt{2}b}{2}$.

Comment: If the triangle were isosceles, then it would be silly to reference both "$b$" and "$c$" in the formula. @kmitov has it correct in his comment that the more-likely fix is to take $t_A$ as the *bisector* of $\angle A$.